# GMail not allowing "send mail as", saying Server returned error: "TLS Negotiation failed, the certificate doesn't match the host., code: 0"

Tags: postfix, gmail

So I am trying to set up my GMail account so I can send emails so they appear to come from various addresses in my small handful of domains. When I click on the "Save Changes" button I get the following error:

Authentication failed. Please check your username/password.
Server returned error: "TLS Negotiation failed, the certificate doesn't match the host., code: 0"

Searching tells me Google added some extra verification steps to doing this involving reverse resolution of the IP address, but even when I account for that it still fails.

I'm doing this with Postfix on FreeBSD 12.1.

When I look at the Postfix log, I see the expected SMTP conversation:

```
Jul 18 13:10:09 authns2 postfix/submission/smtpd[65083]: > mail-io1-xd2b.google.com[2607:f8b0:4864:20::d2b]:41918: 220 mail2.example.com ESMTP Postfix
Jul 18 13:10:09 authns2 postfix/submission/smtpd[65083]: xsasl_cyrus_server_create: SASL service=smtp, realm=example.com
Jul 18 13:10:09 authns2 postfix/submission/smtpd[65083]: name_mask: noanonymous
Jul 18 13:10:09 authns2 postfix/submission/smtpd[65083]: < mail-io1-xd2b.google.com[2607:f8b0:4864:20::d2b]:41918: EHLO mail-io1-xd2b.google.com
Jul 18 13:10:09 authns2 postfix/submission/smtpd[65083]: match_list_match: mail-io1-xd2b.google.com: no match
Jul 18 13:10:09 authns2 postfix/submission/smtpd[65083]: match_list_match: 2607:f8b0:4864:20::d2b: no match
Jul 18 13:10:09 authns2 postfix/submission/smtpd[65083]: > mail-io1-xd2b.google.com[2607:f8b0:4864:20::d2b]:41918: 250-mail2.example.name
Jul 18 13:10:09 authns2 postfix/submission/smtpd[65083]: > mail-io1-xd2b.google.com[2607:f8b0:4864:20::d2b]:41918: 250-PIPELINING
Jul 18 13:10:09 authns2 postfix/submission/smtpd[65083]: > mail-io1-xd2b.google.com[2607:f8b0:4864:20::d2b]:41918: 250-SIZE 10240000
Jul 18 13:10:09 authns2 postfix/submission/smtpd[65083]: > mail-io1-xd2b.google.com[2607:f8b0:4864:20::d2b]:41918: 250-ETRN
Jul 18 13:10:09 authns2 postfix/submission/smtpd[65083]: > mail-io1-xd2b.google.com[2607:f8b0:4864:20::d2b]:41918: 250-STARTTLS
Jul 18 13:10:09 authns2 postfix/submission/smtpd[65083]: > mail-io1-xd2b.google.com[2607:f8b0:4864:20::d2b]:41918: 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
Jul 18 13:10:09 authns2 postfix/submission/smtpd[65083]: > mail-io1-xd2b.google.com[2607:f8b0:4864:20::d2b]:41918: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Jul 18 13:10:09 authns2 postfix/submission/smtpd[65083]: > mail-io1-xd2b.google.com[2607:f8b0:4864:20::d2b]:41918: 250-8BITMIME
Jul 18 13:10:09 authns2 postfix/submission/smtpd[65083]: > mail-io1-xd2b.google.com[2607:f8b0:4864:20::d2b]:41918: 250-DSN
Jul 18 13:10:09 authns2 postfix/submission/smtpd[65083]: > mail-io1-xd2b.google.com[2607:f8b0:4864:20::d2b]:41918: 250-SMTPUTF8
Jul 18 13:10:09 authns2 postfix/submission/smtpd[65083]: > mail-io1-xd2b.google.com[2607:f8b0:4864:20::d2b]:41918: 250 CHUNKING
Jul 18 13:10:09 authns2 postfix/submission/smtpd[65083]: < mail-io1-xd2b.google.com[2607:f8b0:4864:20::d2b]:41918: STARTTLS
Jul 18 13:10:09 authns2 postfix/submission/smtpd[65083]: > mail-io1-xd2b.google.com[2607:f8b0:4864:20::d2b]:41918: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
```

It continues with setting up a TLS session which is successful, but then Google drops the connection without trying to AUTH like it does with an unsecured connection. (For which it is successful, so I know that it's not Postfix+SASL being misconfigured causing the issue)

The certificate is for mail2.example.com with a subject alt-name attribute of

```
DNS:mail.example.com, DNS:mail2.example.com, DNS:mail2.example2.com, DNS:mail2.example3.com
```

The actual host that is mail2.example.com has IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, but both of those have DNS PTR recodes tthat point to it.

All of that matches what Postfix announces itself as in the initial 220 response when the Google server connects.

1. name in 220 reply: mail2.example.com
2. certificate name: mail2.example.com
3. reverse DNS resolution for both IPv4 and IPv6: mail2.example.com
4. credentials working

That should be enough to make this work, right? Of has my googling not uncovered all the steps?

Could it matter that I am using my own self-created root CA to sign that signature with? Since these are just stuff that I play with, I never saw the need to buy a very expensive cert that could be used to sign other certs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems Google have started enforcing stricter condition, and it looks like self signed certificates are not well viewed.
If price is your only pain point you can get a free one from Let's Encrypt.

For info, google require the fullchain of certificate to be sent. Hard to say if that's the case for you.

Links talking about Google TLS strictness:
[Google thread](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/38336515?hl=en)
[Stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61299867/tls-negotiation-failed-the-certificate-doesnt-match-the-host-code-0)

Comment: I have my own root CA's cert in the chain of the host cert, but the problem still happens. I thought of going for one of those cheapie certs, but I really just want something I can set and forget and not have to remember every year to get a new one.

Comment: 'Your root CA' means it's a self signed certificates, which won't go well with Google. If you want a set and forget thing for TLS, you should look at 'certbot' which will auto renew your certificates every 3 months as long as you own the domain.